# How to find the length of characters in a string using Scala Spark

Tags: scala

I am trying to find the number of occurrences of a character in a string 
In the below string I need to find the the count of first occurrence of "c" and the count of the second occurrence of "c"

```
Ex: "abccccsdegccccccd"
```

For the above the result should be 4 and 6

```
val test = "abccccsdegccccccd"
test.split("c",-1)
res33: Array[String] = Array(ab, "", "", "", sdeg, "", "", "", "", "", d)
```

I tried using normal split but I did not get the expected results.The index of "c" can change in the next string.

Your help is appreciated.Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the lengths of all 'c' sequences.

```
test.split("[^c]").collect{case s if s.nonEmpty => s.length}
// res0: Array[Int] = Array(4, 6)
```

Returns an empty `Array[Int]` if there are no 'c' characters in the string.

Comment: Thank you jwch ,this is much precise way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a regex:

```
val regex = "[^c]+(c+)[^c]+(c+).*".r
val result = "abccccsdegccccccd" match {
  case regex(first, second) => (first.size, second.size)
}
```

Or with `dropWhile` and `takeWhile`, which either drop off the first part of the string, or take only the first part of the string that matches some condition, respectively:

```
val firstLen = str.dropWhile(_ != 'c').takeWhile(_ == 'c').size
val secondLen = str.dropWhile(_ != 'c').dropWhile(_ == 'c').dropWhile(_ != 'c').takeWhile(_ == 'c').size
```

The former won't work if there aren't two groups of 'c's, the latter will (the result will be 0).